# Is there a way to avoid explicit type annotation on parameters that take instances of classes in F#?

Tags: f#

Type inference in F# doesn't seem to work very well with parameters that are supposed to take values of a class type.
Is there a way to avoid explicit type annotation on such parameters?
It looks like a problem because when there are some 5 of such parameters each of which requires its pair of parentheses and a colon and the name of a type it looks much messier than the same declaration in C# which is known for being more syntactically noisy.

So that instead of

```
let writeXmlAttribute (writer: XmlWriter) name value = ()
```

I wish I could write something like

```
let writeXmlAttribute writer name value = () // <-- a problem when in comes to writer.WriteStartAttribute name
```

Is there a way I can get away with it?

UPDATE:

There is no such problem with records, only on classes.

Comment: Normally excessive annotations are indicative of non idiomatic for code.

Comment: I agree but this is what you have to deal with working with 3rd party .NET libraries

Comment: As well as standard libraries like System.Xml

Answer (score 3):

If your primary reason for wanting to avoid this is a cleaner signature, you could move the explicit typing into the function with an upcast (which will infer the parameter type due to it being a compile-time determination). You're not avoiding it, however, you're just moving it.

```
let writeXmlAttribute writer name value = 
    (writer :> XmlWriter).WriteStartAttribute(name, value)
```

F# has difficulty with the kind of inference you're asking for in relation to members (including members on records), so you will have to do at least a minimal amount of explicit typing in any case.